# How to create a custom Makefile target using qmake

Tags: qt4, qmake

As far as I understand **qmake** processes a **.pro** file to generate the Makefile used to build the actual qt application.

That said, how can I let qmake generate a Makefile with some custom Makefile target?

Specifically I'd like to have in the Makefile a target called "*package*" that will run all the steps required to create the package for my freshly compiled qt application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using "QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS" as described in [The Power of QMake](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2008/04/16/the-power-of-qmake/).